# How to set `Content-Type` in headers in Axios?

Tags: axios, http-headers

I'm having trouble setting the `Content-Type` header in axios.
Here's my code:

```
axios({
    url: fetchUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(fetchOptions.body),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
      Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
    },
  })
```

And here's the request headers:

[image: axios request headers]

`Accept` is set correctly but `Content-Type` is not.  (Confirmed by removing `Accept` in my code, in which case the request header reverts to `json` isntead of `vnd.api+json`.)

When I change `Content-Type` to `ContentType`, then I see `ContentType` in the Response headers, so the problem is specifically with `Content-Type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that this error was the result of having an empty `data`; the property was called `data`, but I mistakenly called `body`:

```
axios({
    url: fetchUrl,
    data: JSON.stringify(fetchOptions.data),
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.api+json',
      Accept: 'application/vnd.api+json',
    },
  })
```